# C# Webbrowser remove dots fron url

Tags: c#, browser

I have a C# WebBrowser object in my app, but when I make it navigate to a url containing a dot somewhere in the path it just removes the dot..
For example: if I tell it to navigate to this url: http://example.com/hello-./page.html
It will navigate to this: url: http://example.com/hello-/page.html

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is because of a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/179248/when-parsing-a-uri-trailing-dots-are-automatically-removed-from-the-path-without-chance-to-override) with the `System.Uri` class. I'm not aware of a workaround in code, which means you'll need to point to a different URL (maybe one which redirects to your desired URL?), one which doesn't have a `.` before the `/`.